# PL/SQL procedure Country_demographic

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am stuck with project for a class in which I need to create a package called Travelers assistance. I have been writing up the procedures individually at the moment to see if they work by themselves.

I am stuck on a package `country_demographic` which is supposed to pull up certain information on a specified country (can be found in `DBMS_output.put_line section`). The procedure creates without any hassle and I was on here before and amended parts of my code as per a similar conundrum I found, but trying to invoke that procedure using PL/SQL I have came across `A numeric or value error`.

If anyone could look over my code and get back to me in a prompt fashion you will get my thanks.

Below is my code for the plsql procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE country_demographic (p_country_name IN countries.country_name%TYPE)
IS
TYPE ED_TYPE IS TABLE OF countries%ROWTYPE;
p_country_demo_rec ED_TYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO p_country_demo_rec FROM countries
WHERE country_name = p_country_name;
FOR i IN p_country_demo_rec.FIRST..p_country_demo_rec.LAST
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country Name:'||p_country_demo_rec(i).country_name ||
    'Location:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).location ||
    'Capitol:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).capitol ||
    'Population:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).population ||
    'Airports:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).airports ||
    'Climate:' || p_country_demo_rec(i).climate );
END LOOP;
IF SQL%NOTFOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20201, 'This country does not exist.');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do and show what you have tried and the results you get, including any errors or messages. If you want people to help you, you should show your [mcve] as searchable, copyable text. (No one will visit that link, which will be dead in an internet moment.) What we see here are some unclear requirements. Learning this stuff can be stressful, but since your project is coming due you don't have a lot of choice here. The best way to finish the project is to start it.

Comment: Rather than talking about "ritualistic sacrifice of livestock", why don't you say what you are trying achieve with your SQL query.  Also like jdv states above, you need to edit your post and include the text of the query, not an image. No one is going to type that in when they can copy /paste.

Comment: Edited the text to make it clearer, removed extra comments.  Transcribed image into text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your table(s) so I used Scott's schema.

This is what you currently have:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number)
  2  is
  3    type ed_type is table of emp%rowtype;
  4    p_emp_demo_rec ed_type;
  5  begin
  6    select * bulk collect into p_emp_demo_rec
  7      from emp
  8      where deptno = par_deptno;
  9
 10    for i in p_emp_demo_rec.first .. p_emp_demo_rec.last loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line('Empno: ' || p_emp_demo_rec(i).empno ||
 12        'Ename: ' || p_emp_demo_rec(i).ename
 13        );
 14    end loop;
 15
 16    if sql%notfound then
 17       raise_application_Error(-20201, 'This does not exist');
 18    end if;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's test it: first, a DEPTNO that exists:

```
SQL> exec p_test(10);
Empno: 7782Ename: CLARK
Empno: 7839Ename: KING
Empno: 7934Ename: MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now, a DEPTNO that doesn't exist:

```
SQL> exec p_test(-2);
BEGIN p_test(-2); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 10
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

Wooops! Error! Which line is line 10?

```
10    for i in p_emp_demo_rec.first .. p_emp_demo_rec.last loop
```

If nothing was fetched, then first nor last exist and FOR raised an error. It means that you should move IF in front of the FOR loop, i.e.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_deptno in number)
  2  is
  3    type ed_type is table of emp%rowtype;
  4    p_emp_demo_rec ed_type;
  5  begin
  6    select * bulk collect into p_emp_demo_rec
  7      from emp
  8      where deptno = par_deptno;
  9
 10    if sql%notfound then                                       --> this was moved up
 11       raise_application_Error(-20201, 'This does not exist');
 12    end if;
 13
 14    for i in p_emp_demo_rec.first .. p_emp_demo_rec.last loop
 15      dbms_output.put_line('Empno: ' || p_emp_demo_rec(i).empno ||
 16        'Ename: ' || p_emp_demo_rec(i).ename
 17        );
 18    end loop;
 19  end;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_test(-2);
BEGIN p_test(-2); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20201: This does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P_TEST", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Well, yes - that's your `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` and not `NUMERIC OR VALUE ERROR`.

So, a little copy/paste should fix it.

Comment: Dude you're a life saver. Saved me from a fugue state of frustration. I knew it'd be a little tinker, was just too close to it to see what. Hope you didn't roll the eyes like I predicted. Shall henceforth commit to a yearly ritualistic sacrifice of livestock in your honor. Any preferences on what animal?

Comment: hahahah! I think I'll renounce the sacrifice. Accepting the answer will be just fine :)